# Why would closing a dead tcp-socket affect another open tcp socket?

Tags: linux, windows, sockets, networking, nat

We are facing a strange problem that closing a dead tcp socket (caused by unplugged the wire) would affect another normal open tcp socket. below is the detailed information:

1. Topology
   Client A ←→ Switch A ← Router A:NAT ← .. Network .. 
              → Router B:NAT → Switch B ←→ Server B
2. Problem:
   Suppose between the client and the server, there is a dead connection which is caused by unplugging the wire. After unplugging the cable (between the machine and the switch) we login the client A from another machine and now there would be a new tcp connection between client and Server and this connection is OK.

   **We find that, from server, if we close the dead tcp connection while the tcp kernel is still retransmitting data, then the other tcp connection would seem to be polluted and the direction from client to the server would become unavailable which means data sent by client via the connection would never be received by the server, but what surprised us is the other direction -- from the server to the client -- remains OK, via the same tcp socket data sent by the server reached the client machine.**

   But if we wait until the tcp data transmission of the dead connection stops,e.g. 2 hours, and then close the socket, then the other tcp connection remains OK.

**Here are the detailed steps for this issue:**
**1. There are two clients which are both behind Router A: NAT， the NAT is full-cone.**
**2. There is a linux server behind Router B:NAT, the NAT is full-cone, but here it uses        port forwarding.**
**3. Four machines, and two clients say they are X, Y, the server Say it is S**.
**4. X and Y login and setup a video meeting, now they both create a tcp connection to the server, say they are channel CX and channel CY**
**5. Unplug the cable of machine on which Y client is running, now channel CY is broken and dead. But channel CX remains OK.**
**6. Login Y from the fourth machine and setup a video meeting with X again, now there is a new tcp channel, Say it is CY2**.

**Result:**
  **In Step 6, if the server closes the dead connection -- CY --in minutes, then the new channel CY2 would become unidirection -- the data sent from client Y cann't reach the server including the ACK packets while it is ok for the vice verse.**

**if the server closes the dead connection -- CY -- in long time such 2 hours, then NO problem occurs**.

**This problem only happens when running through NATs, at least we never reproduce it when we run the applications within a same LAN (no need to traverse a NAT).**

Does anybody know why it would happen?

Edit:
On the server side, we are using non-blocking tcp sockets and select model.

```
     psuedocode:  
     //server
     listenfd = socket(,SO_STREAM,);
     localAddr.port = htons(8013);
     localAddr.ip = inet_addr(INADDR_ANY);
     bind(localAddr...)
     listen(listenfd, 100);

     ...
     //using select model
     select(maxFd, &fdSet, NULL, NULL);
     for(...)
     {
     if (FD_ISSET(listenfd))
        {
        fd = accept(...)
        set_non_block(fd);
        ...
        }
     ...
     }
```

**More Information:**
**1) connection A on First machine: 192.168.10.4:13000 ←→ ... ← Router A:NAT ← -Now: from PublicIP:8661 (random)..Network .. → Router B:NAT (to port:8013, Port Forwarding) → ... ←→ Server B**

**2) connection B on Second machine: 192.168.10.7:13000 ←→ ... ← Router A:NAT ← -Now: from PublicIP:8777 (random)..Network .. → Router B:NAT (to port:8013, Port Forwarding) → ... ←→ Server B**

**3) unplug the wire and connection A is dead, now create a new connection C on third machine: 192.168.10.10:13000 ←→ ... ← Router A:NAT ← -Now: from PublicIP:8869 (random).. Network .. → Router B:NAT (to port:8013, Port Forwarding) → ... ←→ Server B**

**if we close connection A from server, then connection C would become unidirection, but if we close connection A in 2 hours from server, then connection C remains OK.**

Comment: If there is only one route between client A and server B, how is the server establishing a connection with the client when the wire is unplugged?

Comment: @user315052 there are many machines connecting to the switch in the LAN, all these machines share a public IP.

Comment: So you are saying you unplugged a cable between the switch and the router, but there may be more than one cable between the switch and router? I am trying to imagine how I would reproduce your problem, but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: @user315052, sorry I didn't say it clearly. We unplugged the cable between the switch and the machine, not the one between the switch and the router.

Comment: something wrong with your server code? seems a logical conclusion to me...

Comment: @StevePeng - you'll find that having detailed log files that report the each socket operation and match that to a corresponding wireshark trace will help in revealing the bug in your code. It's not fun, but since you got a repro case, it shouldn't be hard to track down.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath added more information

Comment: Have you tried reproducing the problem with a very simple configuration where all the client(s) and server(s) are plugged into the same Ethernet switch?  If you can reproduce the problem then, that would be a good clue that there is a bug in your server code... if the bug only appears when running through some NATs, etc, then it might be a problem with the NATs.  (My guess is it's the former though)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner thanks. Yes, we have tried that and the result is the latter one, that is during our test the problem easily happens when running through the NATs, but we never reproduce it when running the applications inside a same LAN without NATs.

Answer (score 2):

Wow, what a conundrum. I do think that I have a possible answer though. And I don't really like the implications - but I guess they are inevitable when looking at the standard ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation#Methods_of_Port_translation) is a wikipedia simplification).

NAT (and especially full-cone) works by giving a client a internal address (ip and port), to match the external address it is trying to reach. Any return traffic is sent internal address and then forwarded to the external address by the router.

Lets use an example to expand this brief explination and show what this means for you...

Suppose you have a NAT gateway, forwarding port 80 to an internal server, the internal destination is also port 80.
The gateway has external IP `n.n.n.n` and internal IP `y.y.y.y`.

When a client connects to `n.n.n.n:80` the NAT server faithfully forwards the request to `y.y.y.y:80`, but in the process it rewrote the IP frame. The sender address is now the NAT gateways internal IP, and the sender port is no longer what the client wrote, but a new one assigned by the NAT gateway.

The new port is assigned by the NAT gateway, yes. But it is assigned as a function of the client IP and the port it tried to access, in this case 80.

All well and good, but... When a client established its second connection the same mapping function is used. This should not pose a problem? Well it can. If the gateway does not distinguish between different client addresses (each connection from a client should have a unique port, ideally), it will simply overwrite the mapping the old connection made.

Thus causing resend traffic from the old socket to be sent to the clients new socket.

Highly undesirable, but possible depending on how the NAT is implemented. And since it seems to be a problem of NAT - it will not show when directly connected...

Now, I already see a hole in my explanation - namely that this would mean that you could not have two sockets open to the same server simultaneously, because any return would be garbled. Well, the only reason I can think of that this works is that the socket is still open - and therefore the gateway does not regard it as dead and then creates a second mapping for that client.

Hope I made at least some sense.

Comment: fredrik, I appreciate your help. I added more information to the end, please have a look.

Comment: The added info nicely illustrates what I at least tried to explain :D The NAT incorrectly redirects the old connections data to the new connection on the client - causing the connection to enter a bad state. It's behaves as a man in the middle DOS attack. It might help if the client port (`13000` in your added info) would be something else for the second connection. Which port is used on the nat public side is irrelevant - it is what happens on the internal side and on the client which is important.

Comment: fredrik, the three connections A,B,C are created on three different machines. And also I tried with random ports other than 13000, the third connection C always become broken after we close the dead connection A. If we don't close connection-A then connection C remains  OK.

Comment: When connection C is broken, we found that data sent from server could reach the client, and can't work vice verse. Even the [Ack] packets sent out by the TCP kernel can't reach the server. I think there are two possible actions we didn't see. 1. The [ACK] packets are redirected to another machine other than the server. 2. The [Ack] packets are dropped by some one of the routers by unknown reason.

Comment: Yes, data sent from server would be able to reach the client still. Because the NAT gateway translates them still. But the client connection to the server has been severed.

Comment: Starting to sound as if you have a broken NAT gateway... it should really not behave in that manner. And come to think of it, I've never seen one which does either. Which one is it? And do you have another you can try with?

Comment: I am not sure at the moment, but we are trying to capture packets travelling through router by inserting a HUB device. A hub can be used to capture packets while routers can't.